# Solutions of Blaschke product expression

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Merry Christmas everyone !

This is related to generalizing polynomial inequalities to rational inequalities. Consider the two equations: $z^n=1$ and $z^n=-1,$ whose solutions are, respectively, $z=e^{2 k \pi / {n}}$ and $z=e^{(2 k + 1) \pi / {n}}$, for $k=0,1,2, \dots , n-1.$

The generalization of $z^n=\pm1$ to rational function is the **Blaschke product** of degree $n:$
$$B(z)=\prod_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1-\overline{a_j}z}{z-a_j}.$$
Here each $a_j,$ a pole of $B(z)$, lies outside the unit circle. i.e., $|a_j| >1,$ for each $j.$

Analogous to the polynomial case, I want to find the solutions of $B(z)=1$ and $B(z)=-1.$

I tried by directly manipulating. It was OK for $n=2.$ But for higher orders is there a line of thinking I should consider ? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It is clear to you that the solutions to $B(z)=\pm1$ are all on the unit circle?

Comment: $|z|=1 \iff |B(z)|=1,$ so solutions lie on the unit circle.

Comment: Okay, I was just checking if that was your question. So, are you looking for explicit formulas for the solutions?

Comment: Yes, like $z= ?$ for each case.

Comment: What do you mean by "to find"? Algebraic equations of high degrees cannot be solved by a formula involving arithmetic operations and radicals.

Comment: I don't want a formula per se. What are the solutions of $B(z)=1$ and $B(z)=-1$ ?

Comment: Fib1123 I think the whole issue of inner functions is a red herring. As @AlexandreEremenko has commented above, it is not clear exactly what you are looking for. If you don't want a formula, then do you want some kind of algorithm that will give better and better approximations to solutions?

Comment: @YemonChoi, if there's no way I can come up with solutions for $B(z)=1$ and $B(z)=-1,$ an algorithm is my only hope isn't it. So I can vary the degree and it would give me what my $z'$s are.

Comment: You say "Analogous to the polynomial case", but it is really unclear to me what you mean by this. It would help if you could give some kind of indication of the type of *known* result for *polynomials* that you would like to establish in the case of your Blaschke products. Afaik, there *are* efficient algorithms for finding the zeros of polynomials in one variable. However, it would seem that these should then also work for rational functions, at least in well-conditioned cases. So, again, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: As I've mentioned before, I'm looking for finding solutions of $B(z)=1$ and $B(z)=-1.$ From the comments I understand that I cannot do it.